# bool function for prime numbers

Tags: c++, math

I have the following code for checking whether the first 20 positive numbers are prime using a bool function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

bool prime(int);
/* 
function to evaluate whether a positive integer is prime (true)
or not prime (false)
*/
int main()
{
    for(int x=1; x<=20; x++)
    {
        cout <<  x << " a prime ? (1 yes, 0 no) "
             << prime(x) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool prime(int x)
{
    for(int i=2; i<= sqrt(x); i++)
    {
        if ((x%i) != 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

It works for all numbers `1 to 20` apart from `2 and 3` where the output is `0` instead of `1`. I think I know why. For `x = 2 and 3` there is no `i` in the `for` loop such that `i<=sqrt(2)` or `i<=sqrt(3)`.

How could I modify the code so it would work for these values too?

Also there is an error message `"Control may reach end of non-void function"`. Why is this?

Thanks.

Comment: For printing purpuse, you can add modifier [std::boolalpha](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) to your output line to output boolean value in plain text. `cout <<  x << " a prime ?  " << std::boolapha << prime(x) << endl;`

Answer (score 9):

Modify your prime function to the following

```
bool prime(int x)
{
  if (x < 2) return false;
  for(int i=2; i<= sqrt(x); i++) {
    if ((x%i) == 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

The `Control may reach end of non-void function` error message tells you that your prime function does not return in all cases (When you pass `1` to your function, it does not go in the for loop, and so exit without explicitly returning anything, which could lead to undefined-behavior). In general, you want to have a return instruction outside of any conditionnal structure.

Comment: Thank you. I find the error message disappears with this code. x=1 outputs 1 (a prime) now unfortunately; I want 1 to output 0 (not prime). Maybe you have to consider the case x=1 separately.

Comment: @SamForbes and `x=0`, and `x=-1`, ... too. Only integers above 1 can be prime.

Answer (score 4):

You return in the wrong place in your `prime` function.

```
bool prime(int x) {
    for(int i=2; i<= sqrt(x); i++) {
        if ((x%i) == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In your existing function you only test the very first `i`. The compiler warning refers to how if the loop finishes without returning (although this is easy for us to see it never will), then control will reach the end of `prime` without returning a value.

Comment: Thanks. It should be `return true;` after `if((x%i) != 0)` and return false after. I used this code but it seems to give wrong outputs for lots of the values between 1 and 20. I'm not sure why as I would think its equivalent to @Tom Ahh

Comment: He correctly fixed the condition to `==`, and I didn't notice that the condition was also wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Extract return true result from cycle!

```
bool prime( int _x )
{
    double x = sqrt( _x );
    for( int i = 2; i <= x; ++i )
        if ( !( _x % i ) )
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this without need to sqrt function , there it is

```
bool prime (int num){
int i,temp;
for (i=2; i<=num/2) && temp; i++)
if (num%i==0)
temp = 0;
return temp;}
```