# Slight change to bool prime function

Tags: c++

A while ago I got an answer to a question on how to code a bool function to check if a number is prime: [bool function for prime numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512638/bool-function-for-prime-numbers).

So from this, code that works is

```
bool prime(int x)
{
if (x < 2) return false;
for(int i=2; i<= sqrt(x); i++) {
if ((x%i) == 0) return false;
}
return true;
}
```

However if I change the code to

```
bool prime(int x)
{
if (x < 2) return false;
for(int i=2; i<= sqrt(x); i++) {
if ((x%i) != 0) return true;
}
return false;
}
```

It doesn't correctly determine whether a number is prime for many integers. I would of thought that these two segments of code would be equivalent. Is there any way of making this `bool prime` function work with `!=` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Just because you wanted '!=' if (!((x%i) != 0)) return false; :)

Answer (score 2):

No. When testing if a number is prime, you know that it is not as soon as you find a single factor.

That's why you can break out of the for loop early and return false in your first example:

```
if ((x%i) == 0) return false;
```

Finding that any single number is not a factor does not prove a number to be prime or non-prime, so you cannot terminate early under that condition.

Comment: Ah ok that has cleared it up. I wasn't realising that when returning true/false in the for loop you break out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.

This original code takes advance of the ability to return early if it finds a factor. The modified version returns early the moment it *finds* a factor. Since you have to test *all possible* factors (at least, those less than the square root) before being sure that the number is not prime, the method you propose cannot be made to work.

On a side note, a small change can nearly double the efficiency of the algorithm. Since we don't have to test any even numbers larger than 2, we can test 2 first, then start the loop with 3 and increment by 2s:

```
bool prime(int x)
{
  if (x < 2) return false;
  if (x%2 == 0) return x == 2;
  for(int i=3; i<= sqrt(x); i+=2) {
    if ((x%i) == 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: the 2nd return false; should be return x == 2; as 2 is actually prime

Comment: Thank you. Your answer and others have cleared up my confusion. I wasn't realising that it returned as soon as a factor was found. I suppose you could extend what you said in the side note to any multiple of 3 and so on but this would probably not add much more efficiency with more complicated code.

Comment: Right, there are other optimizations, but this one is the simplest to implement. Others require much more complicated additions to the code.